# Just installed Ubuntu but where to find other add-ons

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu using Wubi. Installation was fantastic and smooth. I've never seen such a smooth installation of OS.

Now when my Ubuntu is ready and running, where I can find those variety of software to integrate with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Application Menu, there's the Software-Center which gives you everything you need.

Comment: Oh yes, that's fantastic. I guess Aptana Studio is not available from there.

Comment: Linux software differs from Windows software,try to find alternatives for your favorite apps

Comment: You can use Aptana Studio for Linux, just download from its own website and install it.

Comment: Have a look at http://alternativeto.net/desktop to find alternative applications :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't really miss out on [synaptic package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) (from system -> admin). **That** is the complete list of available software. The Software centre is just the beginning of a new project and does not offer yet a complete functionality.

All about the repository (the "store" where all software is kept) [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

**EDIT:** There is nothing wrong with the *software centre*... that is exactly thought as an easy way for newcomers to install commonly used software. But if you want to evaluate ubuntu in terms of richness, the software centre simply doesn't make justice to ubuntu.

For commonly used non-free applications, once you have got the basics of repositories, also check out [medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org) (google Earth, Skype, Gizmo5...).